# Append an array to a multidimensional array, preserving the keys

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I have an array called $items :

```
Array
(
    [9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [title] => Fujifilm XE-1 digital camera
        [uri] => fujifilm-xe-1-digital-camera
        [url] => items/fujifilm-xe-1-digital-camera/9
        [cat_id] => 03.01.01.01
    )
)
```

and an array called $item_photos :

```
Array
(
    [photos_dir] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/
    [photos] => Array
    (
        [0] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01xs.jpg
    )

    [main_photos] => Array
    (
        [x_small] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01xs.jpg
        [small] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01s.jpg
        [medium] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01m.jpg
        [large] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01l.jpg
    )
```

I want to append the item photos on to the items array so it become one big array like this (Preserving the number 9 key):

```
Array
 (
     [9] => Array
         (
             [id] => 9
             [title] => Fujifilm XE-1 digital camera
             [uri] => fujifilm-xe-1-digital-camera
             [url] => items/fujifilm-xe-1-digital-camera/9
             [cat_id] => 03.01.01.01
             [photos_dir] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/
             [photos] => Array
             (
                  [0] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01xs.jpg
             )

             [main_photos] => Array
             (
                  [x_small] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01xs.jpg
                  [small] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01s.jpg
                  [medium] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01m.jpg
                  [large] => ../items/item-images/L1/009/01l.jpg
             )
    )
```

I tried `array_push($items, $item_photos);` but it didn't give me the right result.

Comment: Perhaps a merge? $items[6] = array_merge( $item_photos, $items[9]) >

Comment: I think you meant $items[9] = array_merge( $item_photos, $items[9]) which works. If you make it an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it. cheers.

Comment: Is there such thing as vertical dyslexia? I think I may have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option to try:

```
$items[9] = array_merge( $items[9], $item_photos );
```

So it's replacing $items[9] with a merged array that combines $items[9] and $item_photos.